# SalesLineType_Sales extension possible?

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax7

We are looking at doing a customization SalesLineType_Sales, where we need to add validation for "SalesQty" in "pdsMRCCheckRestricted" method below.

Now, we know that customizations are not favored, so looking for any suggestion OR best practice to get it done appropriately.

1- We can customize the "SalesLineType_Sales" - but is this best practice for Dynamics 365 for operations?
2- Any other possible options?

Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

```
public boolean pdsMRCCheckRestricted()
{
    boolean                 isRestricted = false;
    AddressCountryRegionId  deliveryCountryId;
    AddressStateId          deliveryStateId;

    deliveryCountryId = salesLine.deliveryAddress().CountryRegionId ?
        salesLine.deliveryAddress().CountryRegionId : salesTable.deliveryAddress().CountryRegionId;

    deliveryStateId   = salesLine.deliveryAddress().State ?
        salesLine.deliveryAddress().State : salesTable.deliveryAddress().State;

    if (salesLine.SalesQty >  0)
    {

        isRestricted = PdsMRCRestrictedListByItem::checkItemRestrictedForState(
                                         deliveryCountryId,
                                         deliveryStateId,
                                         salesLine.ItemId);
        if (!isRestricted)
        {
            isRestricted =
                PdsMRCRestrictedListByItem::checkItemRestrictedForCountry(
                                            deliveryCountryId,
                                            salesLine.ItemId);
        }

        if (isRestricted)
        {
            error(strFmt("@PDS908", salesLine.ItemId));
        }
    }

    return isRestricted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Dynamics 365 for Operations the preferred mechanism for customizations to existing objects is to use event handlers to react to various events rather than overriding methods on tables, forms, and classes.

```
[PostHandlerFor(classStr(SalesLineType_Sales), methodstr(SalesLineType_Sales, pdsMRCCheckRestricted))]
public static void PostPdsMRCCheckRestricted(XppPrePostArgs args)
{
    boolean     returnValue = args.getReturnValue();        

    //Suppress error message
    if (returnValue)
    {
        infolog.clear();
    }

    //Add your validation here

    args.setReturnValue(returnValue);        
}
```

Comment: Thanks aliaksandr for replying. What would happen with infolog? When result is true it will log the error. if (isRestricted)
        {
            error(strFmt("@PDS908", salesLine.ItemId));
        }